# Помогите разобраться с str.split

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть строка `a`. Методом `split()` мы разделяем строку `a` на список `b`, используя пробел в качестве разделителя.

Почему пробелы находящиеся в списке `b`, которые идут сразу после разделителя питон считает как пустую строку, а не как пробелы? Ведь пробел, вроде как, не является пустой строкой, а в списке `b` именно пробелы.

```py
    a = 'aa aa   aa'  
    b=a.split(' ')  
    i=0  
    for el in b:  
        if b[i]=='': # - пустая строка  
            print(b[i]+': Да') # почему так?  
        if b[i]==' ': # - пробел  
            print(b[i]+': Нет') # а не так?  
        i+=1
```

Comment: Замените: `a.split(' ')` --> `a.split()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Метод [str.split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) по умолчанию (если не указать `sep` или если указать `sep=None`) будет использовать в качестве разделителя любое количество идущих подряд пробелов или символов табуляции.

Пример:

```
In [3]: a.split(' ')
Out[3]: ['aa', 'aa', '', '', 'aa']

In [4]: a.split()
Out[4]: ['aa', 'aa', 'aa']
```